# Maybe a syntax issue here?

Tags: c++, syntax

Homework problem I am helping one of my mentees out with (check my history, I have previously asked help with Java in more advanced programs. This is something simple I can't help her figure out). We need to use a while loop to read in numbers, keep track of the count, and keep summing up the numbers entered. We keep getting an error in line 24. Even when I comment it out and run it, the programs doesn't do what it is supposed to do. Been forever since I've done a program in C++ and I need the help of you guys!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num;
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    float avg;

    cout << "Enter numbers, 999 to quit" << endl; 
    cin >> num; // 

    while (num != 999) 
    {
        cout << "Number entered is" <<  num << endl;
        cout << "Enter numbers, 999 to quit" << endl;
        cin >> num;
        sum = sum + num;
        count++;
}
    cout << "Total numbers entered: " + count << endl;
    cout << "Sum of numbers entered is " + sum << endl;
    avg = sum/count;
    cout << "Average of numbers entered:" + avg << endl;



    return 0;




}
```

Comment: OK so John Kugelman helped me with that part. Below is the output I get when I enter 10 three times. 


Enter numbers, 999 to quit
10
Number entered is  10
Enter numbers, 999 to quit
10
Number entered is  10
Enter numbers, 999 to quit
10
Number entered is  10
Enter numbers, 999 to quit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cout << "Total numbers entered: " + count << endl;
cout << "Sum of numbers entered is " + sum << endl;
avg = sum/count;
cout << "Average of numbers entered:" + avg << endl;
```

Change those `+`'s to `<<`'s.

```
cout << "Total numbers entered: " << count << endl;
cout << "Sum of numbers entered is " << sum << endl;
avg = sum/count;
cout << "Average of numbers entered:" << avg << endl;
```

Comment: ahh thanks! that's me trying to use java syntax instead of c++

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num,count;
    float sum,average;

    cout << "Enter numbers, 999 to quit" << endl;
    cin>>num;
    count=0;
    sum=0;


    while (num!=999)
    {
        cout<<"Number entered is"<<num<<endl;
        ++count;
        sum+=num;
        cout << "Enter numbers, 999 to quit" << endl;
        cin>>num;
    }
    if (count==0) {
        count=1;
    }// if the first number you enter is 999 count should be 1 
     // , otherwise avg will be (sum/0 ),which doesn't make sense.

    cout << "Total numbers entered: " <<count << endl;
    cout << "Sum of numbers entered is " <<sum << endl;
    average = sum/count;
    cout << "Average of numbers entered:"<<average << endl;
// use << not + because "Total..." is string type and count is int type
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

You should pay attention to the type of variable when you do something,which often can cause small errors.